# Prim's algorithm question

Tags: graph-theory

How to use Prim’s algorithm to find the minimal spanning tree for the following weighted graph, starting from the edge CE. What is the total minimum weight? Im confuse with this graph chapter as it has many ways to find.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm works by starting at a vertex and adding all of that vertex's edges to a priority queue. Poll the lowest weight edge. If it does not create a cycle, add it. The vertex at the other end has all of its unused edges added to the priority queue. We then repeat until we have a spanning tree.

Visually, you look at all touched vertices and choose the minimum weight edge that doesn't create a cycle. So starting at $C$, we choose $CE$. We then choose $ED$. Next, $EB$. Finally, $DA$.

Do you see how I got that?